# Perforce jenkins multi pipelines

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, perforce, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I am facing an issue with P4 plugin in which jenkins detects branches even though the Jenkinsfile has been deleted.

From the log, `p4 files //depot/branch/branchName/Jenkinsfile` seems to be the problem which returns saying the file is deleted in the changelist xxxx and that doesn't prevent jenkins for detecting that branch.

Is there a way to tackle this issue with P4 plugin to ignore branches with deleted Jenkinsfile?

Answer (score 1):

With a reasonably modern server, 'p4 files -e' might be what you are looking for:

> The -e flag displays files with an action of anything other than
>       deleted, purged or archived.  Typically this revision is always
>       available to sync or integrate from.

The `-e` flag will prevent your `p4 files` command from returning files which have been deleted.

Comment: Hey Bryan, awesome I've actually tried that but was more thinking how to do that from the Jenkins P4 plugin perspective

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed it by making sure all Jenkinsfile's revisions are deleted `p4 obliterate /path/Jenkinsfile`